# How to setup a MEAN in Windows 7

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have done a node.js server install and checked the `node --version` in the command prompt

[image]

[image]

I have done this much but I couldn't stat the npm.

Comment: Getting MEAN
with Mongo, Express,
Angular, and Node
SIMON HOLMES ,I'am referring this pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed nodeJs already on your computer. But I will explain step by step how to setup a project with MongoDb + express + Angular + NodeJs

1. **Install MongoDB, Configure and Run** - Download MongiDb installer and install MongoDB on your computer. Follow the screen instructions. Read installation guide for windows [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)
2. **Install NodeJs** - [Download](https://nodejs.org/en/) and install NodeJs. Open command prompt and type "`node -v`", if this command runs without an issue, that mean you have installed NodeJs on your computer
3. **Setup a project** -  Create a empty folder. Open command prompt and go inside the folder. Now type `npm init`. Provide answers for questions prompt in command prompt. Once you complete that you can see `package.json` file is created in your folder.
4. **Install express** - To install express type `npm install express --save`
5. **Install bower package manager** - Run `npm install -g bower` if you don't installed bower before on your computer. (Bower is a package manager for font end websites.)
6. **Install AngularJs** - Run `bower install angular --save` command to install angular
7. **Create a NodeJs Server** - Create a file index.js. This will be an entry point of your nodeJs app

   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.send('Hello World!')
   })

   app.listen(3000, function () {
     console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
   })
8. Run `node index.js`. Your website is now running on http://localhost:3000.

Please read some tutorial [here](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/09/28/angularjs-tutorial-for-beginners-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb/) to get more information

Comment: C:\jeevan>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (jeevan) jeevan
version: (1.0.0) 1
Invalid version: "1"
version: (1.0.0)

Comment: Javeen, Version should be something like 1.0.0. Please read more about software version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791121/what-every-digit-means-in-software-version-1-7-1-0-for-example

Comment: npm install -g express-generator  and after create new folder and command promt 1.express ,2.npm install ,3.npm start its worked.  i used like this my issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you have every thing installed (Mongo,Node) then you can try yeoman application generator.It will create a sample application for you with all the required folders and you just need node modules and bower components to install.

Please read this here:-
http://yeoman.io/

You don't need to bother any thing for any of your folders